# Can we use GPIO_PinAFConfig function to make a pin as output on STM32L1?

Tags: embedded, stm32ldiscovery

I'm using stm32l100rc board. I need to make a pin output/input several times so can I use GPIO_PinAFConfig function to do that? or do I have to initialize whole GPIO_InitTypeDef structure for it.

Answer (score 1):

A GPIO can be configured as either an input, output, or one of possibly several alternate functions.  As its name suggests, `GPIO_PinAFConfig` sets one of those alternate functions, so would not achieve your aim at all.

If switching between input and output using the standard peripheral library, there will be some redundancy - register values that do not change, or which are mutually exclusive to input or output.  If you need the switch to be as fast as possible (and we are talking tens or hundreds of nanoseconds here), then direct register access might make significant savings by changing only those registers necessarily necessary.